# How to clone a prop and change a specific data

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to edit a props before dispatch to redux state? Basically you cannot mutate your state so I have to assign an entire new data.

```
const graphQLReturnedData = [

  { id: 1, foo: "bar", <longer-list> },
  { id: 2, foo: "pub", <longer-list> },

]


graphQLReturnedData.find(t => t.id === 1  ).foo = "me"; // Cannot assign to read only property...
```

The exact question is, how to clone a prop and change an object value? No luck with

```
var newData = Object.assign({}, graphQLReturnedData)
newData.find(t => t.id === 1  ).foo = "phew";
```

Redux needs an entire new data when I only need to change a small value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Object.assign` clones the array object, but the elements in it are still the same objects with read-only properties. If you use a `map`, you can return a new array with a new object for the appropriate `id` (assuming `id`'s are unique in the array):

```
const newData = graphQLReturnedData.map(t => t.id !== 1 ? t : {...t, foo: "me"});
```

or, using `Object.assign`:

```
const newData = graphQLReturnedData.map(
  t => t.id !== 1 ? t : Object.assign({}, t, {foo: "me"})
);
```